# cudaMemcpy/cudaMemcpyToSymbol gives invalid argument error

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm having trouble with copying a struct pa on the host to a struct pointer d_pa on the device. In an attempt to make a minimal version I tried two different approaches as shown below. Both times my errCheck Makro gives an error message "GPUassert: invalid argument stackoverflow.cu 42". With 42 being either the line of either cudaMemcpy depending on which I comment out. Without the errCheck Makro it prints out zero for the device variables.

stackoverflow.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

//Header File:

#define errCheck(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

typedef struct{
  int a;
  double b; //some parameters
} params;

extern __device__ params *d_pa; //params struct on the device
```

stackoverflow.cu

```
#include "stackoverflow.h"

//.cu file:
__device__ params *d_pa;
params pa;

__global__ void paramsDeviceInit() {
  d_pa = (params*)malloc(sizeof(params)); //sizeof(params)
}

void setParams() {
    pa.a=1;
    pa.b=2;

    paramsDeviceInit<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    //Version 1:
    errCheck(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_pa,&pa,sizeof(params)));

    //Version 2:
    params *dev_pa;
    errCheck(cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&dev_pa, d_pa));
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    errCheck(cudaMemcpy(dev_pa, &pa, sizeof(params), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    printf("Host: a=%d, b=%f\n",pa.a,pa.b);
}

int main(){
    setParams();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some immediate problems:

- The entity that you declare in the `__device__` declaration is the *only* thing you can copy to from a host API like `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` (or `cudaMemcpy`, for that matter).  Since you have declared a pointer, that is the only thing you can copy to, the pointer itself, not what the pointer points to.
- An allocation created with in-kernel `malloc` (or in-kernel `new`) [*cannot* participate](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#interoperability-host-memory-api) in a transfer via a host API (e.g. `cudaMemcpy`). So that is a non-starter.

There are any number of ways to fix this issue.  I personally don't recommend this:

```
   __device__ <type> *<ptr_name>;
```

I find that construct to be [confusing and inconvenient to work with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878410/cuda-object-copy/49879609#49879609).  So as a "solution" I will suggest that we convert the `__device__` ptr to just a `__device__` object, as in the following:

```
$ cat t1862.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//Header File:

#define errCheck(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

typedef struct{
  int a;
  double b; //some parameters
} params;

__device__ params d_pa;
params pa;

__global__ void paramsDeviceInit() {
  d_pa.a = 0;
  d_pa.b = 0;
}

void setParams() {
    pa.a=1;
    pa.b=2;

    errCheck(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_pa,&pa,sizeof(params)));
    paramsDeviceInit<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    errCheck(cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&pa,d_pa,sizeof(params)));

    printf("Host: a=%d, b=%f\n",pa.a,pa.b);
}

int main(){
    setParams();
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1862 t1862.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1862
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
Host: a=0, b=0.000000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

If you insist on using a `__device__` pointer, then the answer I linked above shows how to manage that.